# How can I specify a branch folder of a monorepo when deploying an Amplify app using the CDK?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-cdk

Currently using the aws console is simple:
[image: add repo folder using aws console]

But I can't find the way to do it using the CDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this can be added with the environement variable:
**AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html

> AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT
>
> The path to use to specify the app root of a monorepo app, relative to
> the root of your repository.
>
> apps/react-app

The AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT environment variable must have the same value as the appRoot key inside the build spec. –

Comment: Thank you. To complement this answer, the AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT environment variable must have the same value of the ```appRoot``` key inside the build spec.

Comment: Sure, Im adding this to the answer :)

Comment: Just to expand on this, you will need to add your env variables in the `environmentVariables` object within the `amplify.App` third argument.